# Yii captha

Tags: jquery, php, yii, javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли такой вот код, генерируемый Yii кинуть в отдельный файл:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {

jQuery(document).on('click', '#yw0', function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "\/my\/path\/captcha?refresh=1",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#yw0').attr('src', data['url']);
            jQuery('body').data('captcha.hash', [data['hash1'], data['hash2']]);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: вопрос задан 16 часов назад.
Ты наверное еже сам попробовал вынести этот код в отдельный файл и получил результат, или я могу ошибаться и ты ждешь что скажут "да/нет"???

Comment: меня смущает вот эта строка url: "\/my\/path\/captcha?refresh=1",

она для каждого контроллера разная генерируется, и я пока не могу сделать ее универсальной для всех.